# What does 「夏がめぐりめぐって」 mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, song-lyrics

It's a line from 森田童子's 雨のクロール

> 夏がめぐりめぐってもぽくはもう決して　泳がないだろう

Source: https://mojim.com/jpy113808x1x2.htm

> めぐりめぐって

Meaning: 多くのところを巡っていって。巡り続けて。(going in circles, from one place to another and coming back again)

Source: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%B7%A1%E3%82%8A%E5%B7%A1%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6/#jn-292048

Why does she say "Summer going around in circles". I think translating it as "Summer coming and going every year" makes more sense but wanted to confirm if this is what it actually means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

巡る has many [meanings](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%B7%A1%E3%82%8B/), one of which is related to the "cycle" of months, seasons or ages:

> ４ まわって再びもとに返る。「春がまた―・ってくる」「―・る月日」

巡り巡って ("around and around", "all the way around") is an emphatic adverb made from 巡る, and it is safely used with 夏, too. In this case it roughly means "no matter how many summers come" or "even many years later in the summer".

There are not many adverbs in the same form, but 積もり積もって and 回り回って are relatively common.

By the way, that **ぽ**く is a mere typo made by the lyrics site. In the original song she is clearly saying ぼく.

Comment: `By the way, that ぽく is a mere typo made by the lyrics site.`

You are correct. It is a typo.